# How to compare two lists of anonymous variables in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, linqpad

[Link to csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z63s6xmr8lgx6dy/1.csv)

I have the following code that filters through a csv file and stores the 1st and 5th column in one list (values) and the 7th and 11th columns in another list (values1).

The aim is to search through each element in the first list (values) and then check every element in the second list (value1) for matching periods before adding all matching cases' payouts and then comparing to the first list's payout with a 1% error margin.

The following code takes care of the searching through each list part with the two foreach loops below. But I am having problems defining a variable (i.e. the var temp does not work and gives me an error of FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format." error when I run the code) to store or add the Payouts together in the event that there are multiple occurrences of a period in the second list.

Also is it possible to define the type of the variable Payout and Period when I define the lists? The problem lies with the fact that they are anonymous variables as supposed to defined ones.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
var values = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1)
      .Select(x => x.Split(','))
      .Where(x => x[0] != string.Empty)
      .Select(x => new { Period = int.Parse(x[0]), Payout = decimal.Parse(x[4]) })
      .ToList();

values = values.OrderBy(x => x.Period)
.ToList();

var values1 = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1)
      .Select(x => x.Split(','))
      .Where(x => x[0] == string.Empty)
      .Select(x => new { Period = int.Parse(x[6]), Payout = decimal.Parse(x[10]) })
      .ToList();
//Console.WriteLine(values1);

values1 = values1.OrderBy(x => x.Period)
.ToList();
//Console.WriteLine(values1[0]);

decimal temp = 0;

foreach (var value in values)
{
    foreach (var value1 in values1)
    {
        if (value.Period == value1.Period)
        {
            temp += value1.Payout;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is value1.Payout? If it's nullable, decimal, or similar you'll get a formatexception on the parse method. Should it be `int.Parse` or `double.Parse`? Maybe define temp explicitly. Instead of two foreach loops you could do a `.Where()` with `.Contains()` to get all the matching entries and then sum them.

Comment: I think the _actual_ problem is with this line: `temp += int.Parse(value1.Payout);` Run the debugger and double-check the values of `value1.Payout` when it fails. If it compiled, then your anonymous type usage is fine, if it fails at runtime with an exception, then somewhere your logic (or the input data) is flawed. EDIT: Also, seems you might be using currency and looking up periods: is this an _integer_ you're parsing or a _decimal_ number? If the latter, use `decimal.Parse` and declare your `temp` as `decimal temp = 0;`

Comment: Also, perhaps I misunderstood, your anonymous types are reading them as strings when you really want to treat them as numbers. Yes, you can strongly type your anonymous types, you just have to produce the right type: try `.Select(x => new { Period = x[0], Payout = decimal.Parse(x[4]) })` and `.Select(x => new { Period = x[6], Payout = decimal.Parse(x[10]) })`

Comment: @ Chris Sinclair - I tried the parsing as int and decimal but I get the error "FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format" on the line where I do the parsing.
var values = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1)
      .Select(x => x.Split(','))
      .Where(x => x[0] != string.Empty)
      .Select(x => new { Period = int.Parse(x[0]), Payout = decimal.Parse(x[4]) })
      .ToList();

Comment: @ SLV - value1.Payout is a string. Because I did not define my list and hence it contains anonymous variables. 
That's a good idea, I'll give that a go, will reply in a few mins

Comment: @SLV - Tried, but could not get the Where() and Contains() to work. Could you show me a quick example so that I can try? Thanks
@ Chris Sinclair - The part where it fails on is line 4 on the word "new" with the "FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format" error message

Comment: @slizorn: This is because you are attempting to convert an invalid string to an integer or decimal. All of the following will fail: `int.Parse("20.5")`, `int.Parse("20z")`, `decimal.Parse("20.5.5")`, `decimal.Parse("20.0m")`. Double-check your input, most likely the data you're reading in is not what you expect it to be. (perhaps your column indexes are off, or perhaps a row in your CSV file is not formatted correctly) EDIT: That is `x[0]` and/or `x[4]` are _not_ valid text to be converted to their respective number types. Add a breakpoint or extract that behaviour so you can debug/test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FormatException means some of your data is not what you expect.

You can use something like the following to check for invalid data.

```
   int dummyPeriod ;
   decimal dummyPayout;

   var badValues = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1)
     .Select(x => x.Split(','))
     .Where(x => !Int32.TryParse(x[0], out dummyPeriod) || 
              !Decimal.TryParse(x[4], out dummyPayout))

     .Select(x => new { Period =  x[0] , Payout = x[4]   })
     .ToList();
```

If you want to just ignore these lines you can invert the selection, eg

```
var values = File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1)
  .Select(x => x.Split(','))
  .Where(x => Int32.TryParse(x[0], out dummyPeriod) && 
              Decimal.TryParse(x[4], out dummyPayout))    
  .Select(x => new { Period = int.Parse(x[0]), Payout = decimal.Parse(x[4]) })
  .ToList();
```

Note that

```
 decimal.parse(x[4])
```

will fail if x[4] is an empty string, whereas you may want to interpret this as zero.

Comment: Ran your code - alas you were right, bunch of blank lines and all those with E in them (i.e. 4.85087482499999E7). The thing is the blank lines I can afford to skip, but all those with E in them, I need them. Is there a way to read the actual value of the cell so that it will return a decimal without the E in it?

Comment: Try `Payout = (decimal) Double.Parse(x[4])` . (Note this may throw an OverflowException if the number is too big to fit in a decimal)

Answer (score 1):

From the line: `.Select(x => new { Period = int.Parse(x[0]), Payout = decimal.Parse(x[4]) })`

This is failing because you are attempting to convert an invalid string to an integer or decimal. All of the following will fail:

```
int.Parse("20.5")
int.Parse("20z")
decimal.Parse("20.5.5")
decimal.Parse("20.0m")
```

Double-check your input, most likely the data you're reading in is not what you expect it to be. That is `x[0]` and/or `x[4]` are not valid text to be converted to their respective number types. Add a breakpoint or extract that behaviour so you can debug/test it to validate your text input.

Perhaps your column indexes are off, or perhaps a row in your CSV file is not formatted correctly.

Comment: the thing is if I do something along the lines of, this works, so not sure I can do anything about the formatting, I have checked it in Notepad++ and everything looks in order: values[0] = new { Period = values[0].Period + 1, Payout = values[0].Payout * 2 }; So is it possible to define temp as an object that takes in period and payout and then update them? :/ really lost as to what to do

Comment: Or rather is there a way to read in a cell's actual value? For example, the cell might show 2.92E+07 which is an invalid decimal but its actual value is 29222661.75?

Comment: @slizorn: Perhaps you should post the CSV file. But first, run it through the debugger and check the values of `x[0]` and `x[4]`: what values are they when it throws the exception? EDIT: And as pointed out by sgmoore, empty/blank strings will fail if you had expected those to produce `0`.

Answer (score 0):

take the double loop out, do the join on period and aggregate payout.

Comment: var combinedPayouts = values[0].Period.Join(values1[0].Period).Aggregate(values1[0].Payout);

That's my miserable attempt at what you suggested. I want to be able to do it on the variable itself but I cannot access the variable without specifying which element of the list I want to use. Help please?

Comment: @DamienJoe you referring to me or @Sushant? I'm confused. Pardon me if I have done anything wrong.

Comment: For a better answer, you could post the actual code changes you propose.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Dur> fList = new List<Dur>();
        fList.Add(new Dur(10));
        fList.Add(new Dur(11));
        fList.Add(new Dur(12));
        fList.Add(new Dur(13));

        List<Sec> sList = new List<Sec>();
        sList.Add(new Sec(20));
        sList.Add(new Sec(22));
        sList.Add(new Sec(11));
        sList.Add(new Sec(10));
        sList.Add(new Sec(25));
        var result = from x in fList
                  join y in sList on x._x equals y._y
                  select x._x;
        var sum = result.Sum();
        Console.Write(sum);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}

class Dur
{
    public Dur(int x)
    {
        _x = x;
    }
    public int _x;
}

class Sec
{
    public Sec(int y)
    {
        _y = y;
    }
    public int _y;
}
```